# What is the title of this song on the Pupa OST?

Tags: music, pupa

What is the title of the song played around [this part](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rEul1jSjgAE&t=7m32s)? I really wanted to know the title of the piano piece or at least the composer. I tried searching for Pupa OSTs but unfortunately only the OP and ED were released.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pupa's OST was composed by [KONISHI Kayo](http://vgmdb.net/artist/9157) and [KONDO Yukio](http://vgmdb.net/artist/9158) (who, together, make up the musical unit [MOKA☆](http://vgmdb.net/artist/9159)). Unfortunately, I think that's as good an answer as you're going to get, given that the soundtrack hasn't been (and, I'm guessing, never will be) released.

If you liked the music in Pupa, perhaps you would like to listen to [the soundtrack of Elfen Lied](http://vgmdb.net/album/37057), which was also composed by Konishi and Kondo.

Comment: Do you know when it's going to be released or is it?

Comment: @EdselJeddRenovalles I kind of doubt it's going to be released - the BD/DVD came out back in March, and it didn't have the soundtrack bundled with it. Pupa sold terribly, and plus, since it's a 4-minute series, there can't have been that much music in the first place (most OSTs are longer than the entirety of Pupa), so I can't imagine there's much financial motivation to release the soundtrack as a separate album.